# Windows - apply timeout value to putty link

Tags: windows, putty

For quick access to a server i'm frequently working on if created a shortcut on my desktop with the following target:

C:\Users{myUser}\Desktop\putty.exe sshuser@domain.com -pw sshpassword

Unfortunately the connection to the server times out after like 60 seconds.
Can i also increase the timeout value for the session i open with this desktop link by adding another parameter to the link? If not what would be the way to do it instead?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change keepalives setting on your putty

[image]

Comment: It's also a good idea to save this particular change to the default profile.. That avoids the need to enter it every time.